# Flask app on ubuntu server in azure not running

Tags: python, azure, flask

I've just started making a flask application on an ubuntu server in azure
[Azure info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CAkL2.png)

Whenever I start the uwsgi server with "sudo systemctl start uwsgi_items_rest" it gives no error but when I try to go to the URL, it doesn't connect.

This issue has been going on for *2 days* and I haven't found any fixes.

---

What the Nginx file config looks like and it is in sites-available and sites-enabled

---

```
server {
    listen 80;
    real_ip_header X-Forwarded-For;
    set_real_ip_from 127.0.0.1;
    server_name localhost;

    location / {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:/var/www/html/items-rest/socket.sock;
        uwsgi_modifier1 30;
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;
    location = 404.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    error_page 500 502  503 504 50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}
```

---

this is the uwsgi service

---

```
[Unit]
Description=uWSGI items rest

[Service]
Environment=DATABASE_URL=postgres://MYUSER:MYPASS@localhost:5432/MYUSER
ExecStart=/var/www/html/items-rest/venv/bin/uwsgi --master --emperor /var/www/html/items-rest/uwsgi.ini --die-on-term --uid MYUSER --gid MYUSER --logto /var/www/html/items-rest/log/emperor.log
Restart=always
KillSignal=SIGQUIT
Type=notify
NotifyAccess=all

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

---

And the uwsgi.ini file

---

```
[uwsgi]
base = /var/www/html/items-rest
app = run
module = %(app)

home = %(base)/venv
pythonpath = %(base)

socket = %(base)/socket.sock

chmod-socket = 777

processes = 8

threads = 8

harakiri = 15

callable = app

logto = /var/www/html/items-rest/log/%n.log
```

---

run is a file and is how I start my app file (run.py)
app is my main file that runs everything (app.py)
and app is the flask variable in the app file (app)

You can see all the non ubuntu specific files here: [Github files](https://github.com/NeilAgar/test-repos)
Note: the uwsgi.ini file isn't updated, you can see it above

Comment: are you trying to connect from external of the machine?  If so is there any firewall rules blocking the port?  Does the connection just time out?

Comment: No there aren't any firewalls and the connection says that it timed out after trying to connect after about 20 seconds

Comment: is nginx running?  https://medium.com/@madhan5000/first-off-check-if-nginx-is-running-e29759bdb2c

Comment: Yes, it is i run it before doing run uwsgi

Comment: have you tried to do a curl from the local machine?  curl http://127.0.0.1 or the URL you are trying to connect to.  could also try telnet 127.0.0.1 80

Comment: I've tried putting it on the local host and it works just fine, it's just that when I put it on the web page it doesn't work

Comment: If I had to guess you probably never created an NSG and the port was never opened.  I would give this a try https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/nsg-quickstart-portal

Comment: Alright I'll give it a try, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of right now I am presuming there was no NSG and it was blocking port 80

If that was the issue then following the steps here to get that setup will work.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/nsg-quickstart-portal